# concatenate .doc files with cat

Tags: cat

I'm trying to concatenate several .doc files none of them bigger than 15 KB, I'm trying the usual

```
cat file1.doc file2.doc file3.doc > new_file.doc
```

But despite the result is an almost 200 KB new .doc file this only shows the first of the original .doc files content.

Any ideas? What I'm doing wrong? It's not possible to concatenate .doc files with cat?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why sysadmins and devs tend to dislike binary formats.

Comment: Yeah! try to explain that to regular user.... 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Wow!! @don_crissti that's a good one that I didn't know!! I'm going to try that cause the user it's using libreoffice and converting into .doc(stupid I know) from now on she'll must be compelled to save her files in .odt or manually merge them herself!! :DDD

Thanks a lot, this is the best answer!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510272/convert-doc-to-txt-via-commandline

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620447/7508077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert files like `*.doc` to `*.html` with the writer from LibreOffice:

```bash
lowriter --convert-to html $doc_filename
```

Then you can `cat` them in any order including formatting and images (if they are in the same directory or if their full path is specified).

Finally, you can use the same command to convert them back to the Word format:

```bash
lowriter --convert-to doc $html_filename
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `.doc` files are in Microsoft Word format, not plain text files that you can concatenate together.

The file's header will actually tell your word processor how the data is organized, therefore only listing the first part.

In order to combine them together, you would need to import them using a word processing application and then append them to each other.

Comment: Bloody Microsoft!!! Always making a hell of my life. 
Thanks Julie.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work, as `.doc`(and many other types of files) have internal structure: Some sort of header containing overview information, and then the contents themselves. If you squash two of those together, in the best case the application will only "see" the first one, or will see that the length doesn't match, or that there is some unexpected stuff after the expected end, and consider the file damaged.

Text files are just a string of lines. Adding another string of lines at the end gives a well-formed, longer, text file. Adding lines to a `.doc` file is a much more involved operation.